# Use Preferences menu item

Tags: macos, qt

I am building an application on Mac in Qt. I am having problems in using preferences menu item already present there.

If possible please provide some Sample code which will enable me to have the QAction on click of Preferences menu item.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in Qt Designer (and inside Qt Creator too)

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/4410/screenshot20091225at407.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/4410/screenshot20091225at407.png)

or in code using [setMenuRole()](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qaction.html#menuRole-prop) method with QAction::PreferencesRole as parameter.